# Object creation from separated json schema files

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-defaults

Now I am building node.js app and my needs are:

1.validate&delete props which are unneccesary before routing

```
app.post('/comments', f_validateAndDeleteUnnecceraryPropsOfRequestBody, function(req, res, next){ ...
```

2.create objects from json schemas before response

```
app.post('/comments', f_validateAndDeleteRequestBody, function(req,res,next){
   ...
    res.json(xxxCreateObjectFromJsonSchema('./jsonSchemas/commentAdded.json'))
}
```

And I want to create separate json schema files like this:

```
- jsonSchemas/ 
    - def_address.json // address schema definition
    - person.json // ...properties:{ address: { $ref: 'def_address.json#address'} ....
    - ....
    - def_response.json // fixed response schema for every request but will be used in other schemas
    - commentAdded.json // properties:{ $ref: 'def_response.json#response' }
```

This way I'm planning to make every object map and when I want to change something that I will have to first change schemas.